# How did Källén get his name attached to $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 2 x y -2 x z- 2 y z$?

Tags: physics

For some reason, everybody refers to the function 
$$\lambda(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 2xy -2xz-2yz$$
as "Källén's triangle function."  (see for example [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunnar_Källén](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunnar_K%C3%A4ll%C3%A9n)).  I understand why its a *triangle* function (because it's proportional the area of a triangle of sides $x$ $y$ and $z$).

But how did Källén get his name attached to it?  Is there a paper of his where he used that combination a lot?

Comment: The Wikipedia article states that the function appears in several kinematic equations, which Kallen presumably studied.

Comment: @HDE226868 Thanks, I already know that (by reading the article).  Would you know which equations in particular he studied, and the papers in which he studied them?

Comment: Nope, not "everybody" calls that function by someone's name. I've never heard a name for this function before I read it here.

Comment: @KCd Thanks, that was exactly what I needed to know.

Answer (score 5):

In 1964 Källén wrote a textbook with the title "Elementary Particle Physics", which introduces the symbol with the words "The $\lambda(x,y,z)$ is a symbol which occurs frequently in this book."

In Wightman's obituary for Gunnar Källén (http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103841217), he states that "A typical remark about
the book was: That is the book on elementary particles the experimentalists really find helpful", which might indicate a certain popularity of the book.

This gives one possible answer to your question.